# C++ initialization of struct containing an array

Tags: c++, static-initialization

I have a structure that more or less follows this pattern:

```
struct sTruct {
   int count;
   struct {
       int A;
       int B;
       int C;
   } array[];   //count is the size of this array
};
```

I would like to be able to initialize these with something like the following syntax:

```
sTruct gInit1 = { 2, { {1,2,3},{4,5,6} }};
```

Really, that initialization syntax (or rather, the compactness of it) is more important than the specific struct layout. I do not have access to the standard containers (embedded platform), but I might be able to replicate some of their behavior if needed.

In final form, I would like to initialize an array of roughly 300 of these sTruct containers at once, just to add one more level of parenthesis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it.  If you gave the array a size you could.  An alternative might be:

```
template < int size >
struct sTruct
{
  struct { int a, int b, int c } array[size];
};
sTruct<2> gInit1 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

But, of course, all your sTructs are different types and so it may not be what you want.  Your only other alternative is going to have to be free-store based and won't give you that syntax until initialization lists in 0x.

Comment: I suppose stuffing different sized sTructs into the same array doesn't make much sense in the first place. I may use something like this template, although I still need to add the "size" variable itself to the outer struct.

Comment: If you like this answer you may as well use boost::array.  It's more or less exactly my answer but can hold anything and acts like a standard container (except it has a static size and can be initialized with aggregate syntax).